# AsyncTask not calling onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Other class:

```
    SpotifyTask st = new SpotifyTask(new Closure<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void executeOnSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            track.setJson(result);
        }
    });

    st.execute("asd");
```

Being SpotifyTask:

```
public class SpotifyTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, JSONObject> {

private final Closure<JSONObject> closure;

public SpotifyTask(Closure<JSONObject> closure) {
    this.closure = closure;
}

public static void getTrack(Closure<JSONObject> closure) {
    new SpotifyTask(closure).execute("asd");
}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
    JSONObject result = null;
    SpotifyCall spcall = new SpotifyCall();
    try {
        result = spcall.getTrack();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
    System.out.println("ASD: on post execute "+result);
    closure.executeOnSuccess(result);
}

}
```

So... doInBackground is running OK, and and returning a JSONObject all right; I know because Im debbuging it and "result" IS a JSONObject.

But onPostExecute is never executed, the debugger never gets there and "ASD: on postexecute "+result is never logged.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if spcall.getTrack(); has a infinite loop somewhere

Comment: spcall.getTrack() is returning OK, and doInBackground result is, indeed, a JSONObject.

Comment: Is your static getTrack() method ibeing called on the UI thread?

Comment: Im not sure what do you mean by "UI Thread"... As you may see on the code I posted, getTrack() is being called from the AsyncTask class that im using (SpotifyTask), on the doInBackground method (That is running perfectly). What do you mean by UI thead? Is it mandatory for all the AsyncTask to run on a UI thread?

Comment: Do not use `System.out.println`, use `Log.d`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was "holding" the UI Thread:

```
    this.status = "loading";
    final Track track = new Track();

    SpotifyTask.getTrack(new Closure<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void executeOnSuccess(JSONObject result) {
            track.setJson(result);
        }
    });

    while (this.status.equals("loading")) {

        if (track.getJson() != null) {
            this.trackUno = track.getJson();
            this.status = "ready";
        } else {
            try {
                System.out.println("Not ready, waiting.");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

As soon I removed the while block, it worked perfectly.

I would have to find another way to "wait" for the call to be complete.

Thanks for your time fellas!